# What is wrong with the following code segment?

Tags: c

```
if (fork()  == 0) {
    printf("Here comes the directory listing\n");
    execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    printf("That is the end of the listing\n");
} else {
   ...  /*----Some legal stuff here */
}
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What problem did you face?

Comment: Unless exec fails this `printf("That is the end of the listing\n");` won't get printed. Does it count as "wrong"?

Comment: You probably want `system` instead, if you want to get control back when `/bin/ls` is done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I printf() after a call to execlp() in a child process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864004/how-do-i-printf-after-a-call-to-execlp-in-a-child-process)

Answer (score 1):

Once you call execlp your current process image will be replaced by ls command. You will not get Printf output. No code after execlp will run

Refere - [How do I printf() after a call to execlp() in a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864004/how-do-i-printf-after-a-call-to-execlp-in-a-child-process)

Comment: also there should probably be a wait call somewhere in the else branch, a good place to put the printf would be after the wait